# how to compare dates in linq

Tags: c#, linq, date, linq-to-entities

I am using linq and I'm trying to compare two date and I'm getting support error I googled it and used examples but still gets the unsupported error - `System.NotSupportedException`, What am I doing wrong ?

//vars

```
int numDaysPassed =Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DaysPassed"]);    
  DateTime todayPlusConfigDays = DateTime.Today.Date.AddDays(numDaysPassed);
```

//option 1

```
List<Customerfiles> Customerfiles = context.Customerfiles.Where(x => x.Status == currentStatus && (x.UpdateDate.Value.Date.CompareTo(todayPlusConfigDays)==0)).ToList<Customerfiles>();
```

//option 2

```
List<Customerfiles> Customerfiles = context.Customerfiles.Where(x => x.Status == currentStatus && (x.UpdateDate.Value.Date == todayPlusConfigDays)).ToList<Customerfiles>();
```

Comment: I assume you use Linq-to-entities or something similar? Please tag your question appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because while the query is in the database layer, LINQ can't convert every function that you call to a similar call in SQL, because these functions simply don't exist in SQL.

Why don't you do a simple comparison?

```
List<Customerfiles> Customerfiles = context.Customerfiles.Where(x => x.Status == currentStatus && x.UpdateDate.Value.Date == todayPlusConfigDays).ToList();
```

If you want to get rid of the problem, without worrying about performance, try this:

```
List<Customerfiles> Customerfiles = context.Customerfiles.ToList().Where(x => x.Status == currentStatus && x.UpdateDate.Value.Date == todayPlusConfigDays).ToList();
```

I just added a "ToList()" in the beggining of the query. That will bring the ALL customerFiles to the memory, which usually is a very bad approach. This way, LINQ can do anything you want, because it doesn't need to convert to SQL functions.

Comment: I am geting the System.NotSupportedException

Comment: could you please post the class "CustomerFiles"?